# How to find a better algorithm taking less Execution Time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, time

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
     
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int *arr=new int [n];
    for(int k=0;n>k;k++)
    {
        cin>>*(arr+k);
    }
    long long sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;
    for(int k=0;n>k;k++)
    {
        sum1=sum1+*(arr+k);
        if(*(arr+k)%2==0)
        sum2++;
        else 
        sum3++;
    }
    cout<<sum1<<" ";
    cout<<sum3<<" ";
    cout<<sum2;
     
    return 0;
}
```

> You're given a sequence of *N* integers, your task is to print sum of them, number of odd integers, and number of even integers respectively.
>
> Input
> The first line of input contains an integer *N* (1≤*N*≤10⁵).
>
> The second line of input contains *N* integers separated by a single space (1≤Ai≤10⁵).
>
> Output
> Print the sum of them, number of odd integers, and number of even integers respectively, separated by a space.
>
> Examples
> **input
>
> 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5**
> **output
>
> 15 3 2**

Is there a better algorithm for this code? I need it to take less Execution Time.
Where can I find better algorithms for any code?

Comment: There is no need for any intermediate array in this code whatsoever. Keep a running tally of every number read, and a pair of running counters respectively bumped by one for the odd/even state of the just-read value. In short everything in your second loop can be done in the first loop, and the array itself can be entirely discarded.

Comment: golden_hacker, 3 sums in the loop not needed.  Increment 2 sums in the loop and compute the third after the loop.

Comment: Why are you using *(arr+k) when arr[k] is so much more readable?

Comment: The “n>k” is equally strange.

Comment: And do you have any actual problems with the performance?

Comment: Does your code produce the output for the example input?

Comment: (@chux-ReinstateMonica: 3 sums are not needed because just one is asked. But similarly, one doesn't need to count even *and* odd inputs, as the total count is known.)

Comment: The problem statement looks 3rd party: Please heed [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to re-use the `N` integers that you have stored in the array, there's no point in storing them. You can get the sum as well as number of odd/even integers as you input them.

Additionally, you don't need `long long` as the input will never get that big, unless you mean 10^5?

Further, whenever you are thinking about improving performance you should take a look at the [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) which in this case is `O(N)` where `N` is the number of integers that you have. From an algorithm point of view with N input there's generally very little that you can do to improve this. Maybe if we're talking streams, you can do some statistics but otherwise this implementation is as good as it gets. In some other situations, while the worst case can't be improved, we can improve the average case, which I don't think is applicable here.

Then you should look at profiling the code. That way you have a clear understanding of where bottlenecks are. For your code, there's probably not too much that can be done reasonably.

If we're trying to squeeze every ounce of performance possible, adjusting the compiler flags can bring some performance gains. You should research these but I would not prioritize this over the above.

I would also improve how you name your variables, but this has no impact on performance.

Comment: i understand what you mean and thanks alot for your help @nevets1219

Comment: I've updated with some more additional details (big O and profiling).

Answer (score 0):

Actually C++ by default synchronizes `cin/cout` with C way of doing I/O - `printf/scanf`, which slows down I/O by quite a lot.

Switching to `printf/scanf` or adding something like `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);`  at the start of main should speed this up a few times.